# Java uncaughtExceptionHandler not working

Tags: java, android, exception, runtimeexception, uncaughtexceptionhandler

I have a global exception handler routine which wraps *some* exceptions in runtime exceptions

Like this

```
public class ExceptionHandler
{
public static void handle(){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
}
```

In the `ExceptionHandler` class I also have a static constructor

```
static
  {
    Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
      @Override
      public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable)
      {
        Throwable t;
        t = throwable;
        if (throwable.getCause() != null)
          t = throwable.getCause();
        Log.e(t.getClass().getName(), t.getMessage(), t);
      }
    };
    Thread.currentThread().setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
  }
```

Problem is, after throwing a RTE it does not enter the `UncaughtExceptionHandler`. Why?

BTW, I can't put it into the main method because there is no main in my Android program.

Comment: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2764394/ideal-way-to-set-global-uncaught-exception-handler-in-android)

Comment: I think the code in static block is not executed, because ExceptionHandler isn't inited because no one uses ExceptionHandler class. [read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560103/best-way-to-force-a-java-class-to-be-loaded). You can extend android's [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) class and place this code there, Application class' constructor is some kind of analog of "main" function.

Answer (score 1):

You can subclass Application class and init your `ExceptionHandler` in `onCreate()` method.

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
    }
}
```

and implement your exception handler there

```
private class ExceptionHandler implements Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler {
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable throwable) {
        processUncaughtException(thread, throwable);
    }
}
```

You may also want to maintain the default exception handler so you can do it before setting it

```
defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
```

Answer (score 0):

The `static` initializer block only gets executed when the class is loaded by the ClassLoader. I'm not an expert in Android but I think you can initialize the exception handler in your main activity class. Just use a static initializer block like you have here or use the `Activity` lifecycle methods like `onCreate`. There is also another option suggested here by [Leonidos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14255143/31136) that might be best for this kind of initializations: Extend the `Application` `class` and put your code there.