# Running Abstract Methods from other classes

Tags: java, abstract-class

Im working on a project and for ease of use I wanted to be able to create a class extending my "Screen" interface and the screen class then be initialised from my main method like this -

```
//Screen Interface
public abstract interface Screen {
    public abstract void init();
}

//Screen Implementation
public class Game implements Screen {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //Do stuff
    }
}

//Main class
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Screen s = new Screen();
        s.init();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work because you cant instantiate an abstract class. I would have tried

```
Screen.init();
```

But you cant call a method like this unless its static.
How can I do what i'm trying to achieve? If I was not clear enough please ask in the comments don't just flag and I will update my question.

EDIT: I know I can instantiate the Game class but that is not the point of this. I am trying to run the init method in every class implementing the Screen Interface so I dont have to specify each one induvidually.

Comment: Also you seem confused between interfaces and abstract classes

Comment: I don't see the point in declaring an interface abstract. It already is, same with the methods. Methods are also public by default. Also, you cannot instantiate abstract classes nor interfaces.

Comment: Say you were able to do something like `Screen.init();`, what subclass should that initialize? Why? This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please clarify.

Comment: You haven't explained what you're trying to accomplish, you're just showing us code that doesn't work because it's not supposed to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was hoping it was possible all sub classes would be run

Comment: There's no way to implicitly access every instance of a class. You would have to keep a collection of instances and call your method on each one in a loop. Or if it's a global initialization procedure, you can make it static and call it once.

Comment: So you want a `static` `init` method implemented in each subtype to be invoked at startup?

Comment: Here's something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3560103/how-to-force-a-class-to-be-initialised

Comment: The way the Java class loader works is that it loads each class into memory the first time you refer to it.  It looks for each class by name on its classpath.  So you need to know the name of a class before you can get the class loader to load it.  There's no way to tell the class loader "load all subclasses of `Screen`" because it doesn't know what to look for.  You'll need to approach this differently.

Comment: @DavidWallace so I would have to pass an instance of my Game class to my Screen class?

Comment: No, not necessarily.  If you have an instance of `Game` you can just run it directly.  But your program has to know which classes you want to instantiate.

Comment: Contrary to my earlier comment, this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/3222638 does actually have a way of getting all the classes in the classpath, and you could fish through them to find which ones are subclasses of `Screen`.  But I _really_ wouldn't recommend approaching this problem that way.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347248/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-the-implementations-of-an-interface-programmatically) *might* help you to get all the subtypes and put them into an array, then loop and initialize all of 'em

Answer (score 2):

why not

```
Game s = new Game ();
s.init ();
```

or probably if you have an actually use for the `Screen` interface then

```
Screen s = new Game ();
s.init ();
```

Also you seem confused between interfaces and abstract classes.. You are defining an interface.  You do not extend `interfaces` and you can not instantiate an `interface`

If you want `init` to be called automatically then I suggest you add it as a static block or call it from you `super` constructor

Comment: Because I don't want to have to do that for every game I create, I want it to initialise all classes implementing the Screen class

Comment: You can't @Hamish

Answer (score 1):

In your above code replace this line

```
Screen s = new Screen();
```

with this line:

```
Screen s = new Game();
```

This will work because of dynamic binding/runtime polymorphism feature of OOPs.
At runtime the Object implementing this method (init()) is determined.

Answer (score -1):

You need to instantiate `Game`, not screen.

Comment: This is a correct answer, but it has no code and the explanation isn't clear

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that was the rule. Thought it was pretty straight forward. No worries.

Comment: Its not a correct answer I want every class implementing Screen to be run not just a single class

Comment: It was a correct answer - You can try this Screen s = new Game () but I believe you are bit confused with some basics.

Comment: Nope it is not you don't understand what i'm trying to achieve read the edit.